# Is this a valid custom React Hook use case?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-router-flux

I'm implementing a solution in a React Native to avoid double taps on React Native Router Flux and I came up with this custom hook. What I really don't know is if this is a valid use case for this. Basically I created this as a hook because I'm using the useRef hook inside it. But maybe just a helper function would've been enough.

I also have a wrapper component for `Pressable` and a HOC for other components that may require `onPress`, this is for the current case where my press function call is neither of both.

Hook:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const timeout = Platform.OS === 'android' ? 2000 : 1000;

const useSafePress = () => {
  const disabled = useRef(false);

  const onSafePress = fn => {
    if (!disabled.current) {
      fn();
      disabled.current = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        disabled.current = false;
      }, timeout);
    }
  };

  return onSafePress;
};

export default useSafePress;
```

Usage:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const onSafePress = useSafePress();

  [...]

  return (
    <SomeOtherComponent
      open={isOpen}
      icon={isOpen ? 'window-close' : 'plus'}
      actions={[
        {
          icon: 'share',
          label: 'Action 1',
          onPress: () => onSafePress(onPressShare),
        },
        {
          icon: 'calendar-month',
          label: 'Action 2',
          onPress: () => onSafePress(onPressCalendar),
        },
      ]}
      color={white}
      onStateChange={onStateChange}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This varies on opinion for sure. In my opinion, you are just wrapping a singular function and maybe it doesn't have enough unique logic to warrant it being a hook.

Either way, this works, and it's really just a stylistic choice. In my projects, I try to only extract hooks when I find myself using a collection of hooks/logic over and over again in multiple places. Or there's lots of common logic that utilize a specific hook.